# Printing to stdout and file simultaneously

Tags: perl, stdout

I have a Perl script with several print statements. Is there a way by which I can direct all of these print statements to a file as well as to stdout simultaneously without duplicating print statements ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [File::Tee](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aTee).

```
use File::Tee qw(tee);

tee STDOUT, '>>', 'some_file.out';

print "w00p w00p";
```

If `File::Tee` is unavailable, it is easily simulated with a pipeline:

```
open my $tee, "|-", "tee some_file.out";
print $tee "w00p w00p";
close $tee;
```

Comment: Caveat machinator - neither solution works on Windows.

Comment: Second method fails if file doesn't exist.