# Is there any difference between File::Tee and opening a pipe to "tee"?

Tags: perl, tee

I have a question about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652958), quoted below, by **friedo** to another question here.  (I don't have permission to comment on it, so I am asking this as a question.)

> "You can use [File::Tee](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Tee).
>
> ```
> use File::Tee qw(tee);
> tee STDOUT, '>>', 'some_file.out';
> print "w00p w00p";
> ```
>
> If `File::Tee` is unavailable, it is easily simulated with a pipeline:
>
> ```
> open my $tee, "|-", "tee some_file.out";
> print $tee "w00p w00p";
> close $tee;
> ```

Are both of these tees the same?  Or is one from Perl and the other from Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're *mostly* the same, but the implementation details differ.

Opening a pipe to `tee some_file.out` forks a new process and runs the Unix / Linux utility program [**`tee(1)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) in it.  This program reads its standard input (i.e. anything you write to the pipe) and writes it both to `some_file.out` as well as to stdout (which it inherits from your program).

Obviously, this will not work under Windows, or on any other system that doesn't provide a Unix-style `tee` command.

---

The [**File::Tee**](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Tee) module, on the other hand, is implemented in pure Perl, and doesn't depend on any external programs.  However, according to its documentation, it *also* works by forking a new process and running what is essentially a Perl reimplementation of the Unix `tee` command under it.  This does have some advantages, as the documentation states:

> "It is implemeted around [fork](https://metacpan.org/module/perlfunc#fork), creating a new process for every tee'ed stream. That way, there are no problems handling the output generated by external programs run with [system](https://metacpan.org/module/perlfunc#system) or by XS modules that don't go through [perlio](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO)."

On the other hand, the use of `fork` has its down sides as well:

> #### "BUGS
>
> Does not work on Windows (patches welcome)."

---

If you do want a pure Perl implementation of the `tee` functionality that works on all platforms, consider using [**IO::Tee**](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Tee) instead.  Unlike File::Tee, this module is implemented using PerlIO and does not use `fork`.
Alas, this also means that it may not correctly capture the output of external programs executed with `system` or XS modules that bypass PerlIO.

Comment: +1 and deleting my answer - i'm messed up it with IO::Tee, the File::Tee is fork based..